# Gram Schmidt, show that two vectors are perpendicular

Tags: linear-algebra

We have the formula for normal equations, where $A$ is a rectangular matrix (**EDIT: It is not! It is a column vector! In this case...**):

$$A^TA\hat{x}=A^Tb$$

from which we obtain:

$$\hat{x}=\frac{A^Tb}{A^TA}$$

[image]

Considering the above, we can make vector $b$ orthogonal to $a$ by finding vector $e$. We know that the required vector, call it $B$ is $b-p$, but since $p$ is just some projection onto $a$, we can call it $A\hat{x}$ and from the normal equations we have that $\hat{x}=\frac{A^Tb}{A^TA}$, so $B=b-\frac{A^Tb}{A^TA}A$.

My question is how does one carry out all the working in:

$$A^T\left(b-\frac{A^Tb}{A^TA}A \right)$$

To show that the value is zero?

I am new to linear algebra, and still not very confident about the operations that I can do.. Like I believe since the matrix is rectangular (matrix $A$), I cannot cancel out the $A^T$ in $\frac{A^Tb}{A^TA}$

Comment: The step $A^TA\hat{x}=A^Tb\implies \hat{x} = \dfrac{A^Tb}{A^TA}$ is not sensible as written: $A^TA$ is a square matrix, not a scalar (unless $A$ itself is a column vector) and so one cannot divide by it as one would a scalar. At best, one has $\hat{x} = (A^T A)^{-1} A^T b$. (If $A^T$ is square and invertible, this simplifies to $\hat{x}=A^{-1} b$. But that won't work if $A$ is rectangular.)

Comment: Hmm. I see. Gilbert Strang in his lecture 17 MIT written it out like I did..

Comment: @KeepitReal That only makes sense when $A$ is a column-vector (an $m \times 1$ matrix), so that $A^TA$ is just a number.   You can divide by a number.  You can't divide by a matrix (if it's bigger than $1 \times 1$).

Comment: (That is, you can divide by a *non-zero* number)

Comment: Yes, i see thanks!

Comment: Yes that is correct actually. A is indeed a column vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question makes sense precisely in the case that $A$ is a non-zero column-vector.  In that case, we can distribute to get
$$
A^T\left(b-\frac{A^Tb}{A^TA}A \right) = \\
A^Tb - \left(\frac{A^Tb}{A^TA}\right)(A^TA) = \\
A^Tb - A^Tb = 0
$$
as desired.